# C How does signed to signed integer conversion work?

Tags: c, integer, twos-complement

How does the computer convert between differently sized signed intgers?

For example when i convert the long long int value 12000000000 to int how does it reduce the value? And how does it handle negative numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does it reduce the value?

From [C11 standard 6.3.1.3p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3):

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

It is not defined how to convert the value - instead, each compiler may have different behavior, but it has to have some documented behavior. Nowadays we live in twos-complement world - it's everywhere the same. Let's take a look at gcc compiler - from ex. [gcc documentation integers implementation-defined behavior](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> - The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).
>
> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

So we have:

> long long int value 12000000000 to int

Let's assume `long long int` has 64 bits and `int` has 32 bits and byte has 8 bits and we use twos-complement, so `INT_MIN = -2147483648` `INT_MAX = 2147483647` and `N` is 32, and `2^N` is, well, 4294967296. You should take a peek at [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and we know that:

```
12000000000 = 3 * 4294967296 + -884901888
```

So it will be *converted* to -884901888. That is *irrelevant* to what format is used to store the number - it can be in any format it wishes.

Now, `gcc` is smart, and while the documentation states the *mathematical* description of the algorithm in modulo arithmetic, you can note that:

```
$ printf("%16llx\n%16x\n", 12000000000ll, (int)12000000000ll);
       2cb417800
        cb417800
```

Ie the mathematical operation of "modulo 2^32" is equal in binary to doing an AND mask with all bits set `num & 0xffffffff`.

> And how does it handle negative numbers?

Exactly the same way, there's just a minus. For example `-12000000000ll` :

```
-12000000000ll = -3 * 4294967296 + 884901888
```

So `(int)-12000000000ll` will be converted to `884901888`. Note that in binary it's just:

```
$ printf("%16llx\n%16x\n", -12000000000ll, (int)-12000000000ll);'
fffffffd34be8800
        34be8800
```

Comment: Note: `printf("%16x\n", (int)12000000000ll);` is UB due to mismatched specifier, but usually a nice UB.

Comment: "So it will be converted to -884901888." --> Even with the assumptions given, the _implementaiton defined behavior_ could go another way.  Still this behavior is overwhelmingly the most common.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to convert an integer representation to a smaller, *signed* type in which it cannot be properly represented (such as your example of trying to convert 12000000000 to a 32-bit `int`) is implementation-defined behaviour. From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the third paragraph being relevant here):

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1   When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is
> unchanged.
> 2   Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
> 3   Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised

Comment: Ok, but how would it work on values that can fit into the range? I found a way to convert down with bitwise operators but i can't figure out how to convert up

Comment: @BjörnMaxJakobsen If the value can fit, then it is unchanged (as per the first paragraph cited).

Comment: "if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged."

Comment: @BjörnMaxJakobsen if you're converting, for example, an `int` to a `long`, I'd assume the sign bit of the `int` is simply extended to the MSBit. However, I don't think the standard says how to do it, it just says that if the value fits in the range of the new type, it should be the same.

Comment: The standard just says  the *value* is unchanged. It doesn't say anything about the representation in memory. That is an implementation detail as far as i know.

Comment: @lulle Indeed. It would be possible to have different representation systems for 64- and 32-bit integers. But that would be insane (at best) or, at the least, *very* spiteful. (Though I have heard rumours that 2's Complement is being required as of the very latest C or C++ Standards.)

Comment: "If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the
following ways:

— the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);

— the sign bit has the value −(2^m) (two’s complement);

— the sign bit has the value −(2^m − 1) (ones’ complement).

Which of these applies is implementation-defined" This is what the standard says

Comment: Additionally, the standard allows for padding bits "representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits". So You can't just assume the representation is always identical on all systems.